# Ubuntu : puppet f5 device config : Partition '' doesn't exist

Tags: ubuntu, security, configuration, ruby, puppet

This is a Puppet question that I've posted on the PuppetLabs forums with no response. I'm also posting here because I'm hoping that with a wider audience I might find someone knowledgeable re Puppet config of f5 devices.

Here is my setup : puppet (v3.2.2) master + agent on single server (Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS) with agent serving as f5_proxy

`http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/f5` provides instructions on using the **puppetlabs-f5** module to install/config the **f5-icontrol** gem on a proxy agent **f5_proxy** responsible for remote configuration of an f5 hardware node.  NOTE: in my case **f5_proxy** is co-located on the puppet server.

I've located the **puppetlabs-f5** module at `/etc/puppet/modules/f5` and in `puppet.conf` I set `modulepath=/etc/puppet/modules/`

In my nodes manifest `site.pp` I've included the section to install the **f5-icontrol** gem on my **f5_proxy** agent :

```
node.pp

node my_f5_proxy {
  include f5

  f5::config { "f5.test.mydomain.com":
    username => 'admin',
    password => 'admin',
    url      => 'f5.test.mydomain.com',
    target   => '/etc/puppet/device/f5.test.mydomain.com.conf'
  }
}
```

And I've pointed my device.conf at the f5  :

```
device.conf

[f5.test.mydomain.com]
type f5
url https://admin:admin@f5.test.mydomain.com/
```

And I've revised my RUBYLIB system environment variable :

```
export RUBYLIB=/etc/puppet/modules/f5/lib:$RUBYLIB
```

But when I attempt `puppet device` , it throws an exception :

```
Error: Can't load f5 for http://f5.test.mydomain.com : Exception caught in Management::urn:iControl:Management/Partition::set_active_partition()
Exception: Common::OperationFailed
        primary_error_code   : 16908289 (0x01020001)
        secondary_error_code : 0
        error_string         : Partition '' doesn't exist
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/network_device.rb:10:in `init'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application/device.rb:190:in `main'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application/device.rb:176:in `each_value'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application/device.rb:176:in `main'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:372:in `run_command'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:364:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:456:in `plugin_hook'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:364:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:504:in `exit_on_fail'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:364:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/command_line.rb:132:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/command_line.rb:86:in `execute'
/usr/bin/puppet:4
```

This is a strange error because my f5 is configured with only the default Common partition, and the f5 docs state that unless a named partition is explicitly stated Common is assumed by default.